# Cauchy's integral formula "type" integral

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $\Gamma$ denote the positively oriented circle of radius $2$ with center at the origin. Let $f$ be an analytic function on $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|>1\}$, and let $$\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z)=0.$$

Prove that

$$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\dfrac{f(\zeta)}{z-\zeta}d\zeta$$,

for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|>2$.

I am quite bad at complex analysis and I would appreciate any hints/directions here. Also, if there are generic methods to attack such problems, please share them as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand what you mean. Is this a hint? It is not clear to me.

Comment: I know that. I have given the title because the form of the integral is like the Cauchy formula. Are you able to give me a direction in which to proceed?

Comment: Do as in Cauchy formulae proof : take $|z|>2$, $\varepsilon >0$ s.t. $\mathcal B(z,\varepsilon )\subset \overline{\mathcal B(0,2)}^c$ and take $r>0$ s.t. $\mathcal B(0,r)\supset \mathcal B(z,\varepsilon )$. Then, cut $\mathcal B(0,r)\setminus \overline{\mathcal B(0,2)}$ in two  simpled connected set $O_1$, $O_2$ s.t. $\bar O_1\cup \bar O_2\subset \overline{\mathcal B(0,r)}\setminus \mathcal B(0,2)$ and apply Cauchy formula on $\bar O_1$ and $\bar O_2 \cup \partial \mathcal B(z,\varepsilon )$... Well Caucy formulae is normally for circle, but maybe yours is a bit more general (I hope)

Comment: This question has already been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812465/an-analytic-function-f-on-z-in-mathbbc-z1?rq=1

Comment: @user667 I see. Thanks for the link. How do you search precisely like this? If I had found this earlier, I wouldn't have posted this question again.

Comment: You can do a math-aware search using approach0. https://approach0.xyz/search/

Comment: @user667 I was not aware of this. Thank you very much!